# QQuickImageProvider "requestedSize" always invalid

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I requested my personal imageprovider, but when I debug this few lines requestedSize is always `{-1,-1}`

```
class XdgIconThemeImageProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    XdgIconThemeImageProvider() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Pixmap){}
    QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
    {
        QIcon ico = QIcon::fromTheme(id);
        QPixmap pm =  ico.isNull() ? QPixmap() : ico.pixmap(100,100);
        *size = pm.size();
        return pm;
    }
};
```

qmlfile

```
Image {
    id: icon
    source: model.decoration
    width: parent.height
    height: width
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Doesn't `requestedSize` depend on how the image is requested from QML? If so, we'd have to see your QML code that declares an image.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: So, my point was that it could be the image that is causing the issues. You should provide a minimal, working example.

Comment: This is somewhat misleading. Do you mean the qml `Image` or the image that is to be displayed? For both see above. QIcon::fromTheme(id) gets the icon and creates the pixmap. model.decoration is an url like "image://XdgIconThemeImageProvider/myImageId". myImageId corresponds to the Freedesktop Icon Theme Specification. Generally spoken this is nothing else than allowed input for  QIcon::fromTheme.

Comment: We need a minimal, running example so that we can check the values of the image's `width` and `height`. As far as I can see, we don't have enough information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's what you're passing to the `sourceSize` property of the Image QML element.

How to deal with the the value: if `(!requested_size.isValid() || requested_size.isNull())` then give native size, otherwise fit in the `requested_size`. Zero in one of the components of the `requested_size` means that the respective dimension is unbounded.

How to process the value (supposing that `native_size(texture_handle)` returns the default size of your image):

```
const QSize size = native_size(texture_handle);

if (requested_size.isValid()) {
    const QSize bounding_size(requested_size.width() > 0 ? requested_size.width() : size.width(), requested_size.height() > 0 ? requested_size.height() : size.height());

    // If requested_size.isEmpty() then the caller don't care how big one or two dimensions can grow.
    return size.scaled(bounding_size, requested_size.isEmpty() && (requested_size.width() > size.width() || requested_size.height() > size.height()) ? Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding : Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
} else {
    return size;
}
```

This code differs a bit from the standard implementation because it allows returning images bigger than their native size. Good for textures, but may or may not be desirable in your case.